# ProGuard - нужен пример простейшей конфигурации

Tags: proguard, android, java

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь использовать ProGuard для обсфукации.
Перепробовал разные варианты из интернета, где приведены разные конфигурации. Что-то совсем не работает, что=то работает, но приложение потом начинает падать в произвольных местах.
Мне нужно бы всего лишь зашифровать имена классов, методов и переменных. Без всяких лишних наворотов.
Помучал мануал прогуарда, но что-то так и не проникся.
Может кто-нибудь знающий приведет рабочий пример, который без всяких наворотов шифрует наименования классов и т.д.?

Comment: Готовую конфигурацию вам никто не предоставит, поскольку конфиг ProGuard'а необходимо затачивать под конкретное приложение, используемые библиотеки, аннотации, etc. С чем именно у вас при обфускации возникают проблемы?

Comment: одна из интересных проблем в том, что например на эмуляторе отказывается работать одно, а на реальном девайсе другое после обсфукации.
ну вот конкретная проблема - не может после обсфукации юзать сервис телефонии наследованный от ITelephony.
пытаюсь прописывать его в конфиге, результат тот же самый

Comment: Прочитайте описание в proguard-android.txt. Там есть возможность отключать обфускацию для некоторых файлов. Скорее всего ITelephony - aidl, поэтому при обфускации все ломается.

Comment: Проковырялся полдня, читая мануал прогуарда и ставя эксперименты. Результат нулевой. Так и не нашел как исключить из обсфукации сервис ITelefony
Максимум что добиься это не обсфуцируется имя самого сервиса и вложенных классов. Всё остальное херится. И при работе вылетают сообщения, что до методов сервиса нельзя достучаться...
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Подскажите, как решить!

Comment: @Demon051 https://github.com/aminzai/Android-AIDL-Sample/blob/master/proguard.cfg попробуйте добавить -keep .....ITelephony

Comment: это знаете ли даже не смешно :(
уж это я сделал в первую очередь. но не всё так просто в прогуарде, как может казаться :(

а по ссылке не пускает, выдает ругательство Invalid Server Certificate...

Comment: Кстати вот о чем подумал, может делов том, что разнесены они по разным пакетам в составе одного приложения?
Ну т.е. есть основной пакет и пакет. где вкрячено описание интерфейса телефонии по которому автоматом создается stub класс...
И при обсфукации каким-=то образом ломается связь между этими пакетами... т.е. из основного нет доступа к телефонии...
------
удалось таки скачать по ссылке пример. там стандартная конфигурация. к тому же, если посмотреть проект повнимательнее, то вроде бы прогуард там не подключеается.
ради интереса подключил конфиг к своему проекту. результат опять же нулевой :

Comment: http://jollydroid.getcourse.ru/notebook/2016-12-29-ProGuard-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно что-то лишнее, надо проверять, что можно выкинуть. В общем вот, что нужно в конфигурации, чтобы прогуард не лез в телефонию:

```
keepclasseswithmembernames class com.android.internal.telephony.** {*;}
keep interface com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$** {*;}
keep class com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$** {
  public <fields>;
  public <methods>;
}
keep class com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub.** {
  public <fields>;
  public <methods>;
}
```

Comment: проверил, работает :)